# When I call a randomized function in a web app it stops being randomized

Tags: web-applications, clojure

I have a function `board/setup-board` which generates a randomized board state as a hashmap. It works fine in the repl. But there's a problem with the web-app. After the app starts, the first time the endpoint `/make-board` is hit, it generates a random board. But every time after that, it returns the same board. If I restart the server I get a new random board, but the subsequent calls returns the same initial board.

This is the code in the web-app

```
(def make-board
  {:status  200
   :headers {"Content-Type" "text/html"}
   :body    (str (board/setup-board))}) ;this is what is not randomized
```

and these are my routes and how I start the app

```
(defroutes app
  (GET "/make-board" [] make-board)
  (GET "/" [] home-page)
  (GET "/login" [] login)
  (not-found "404 not found!"))

(defn -main [& args]
  (jetty/run-jetty (wrap-reload #'app) {:port (Integer/parseInt (first args))}))
```

I tried defining `board/setup-board` as a dynamic var by changing the declaration from `(defn setup-board []` to `(defn ^:dynamic setup-board []` but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling a function here, you are creating a value once
(`def`).  Turn `make-board` into a function (`defn`) and call that.